# Можно ли добавить сертификат к HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect?

Tags: c#

Наверно, задаю очень глупый вопрос, но мне нужно редиректнуть пользователя на url, который я собираю из кусков, и поскольку url ведёт на API банка, им требуется сертификат для работы.

Можно ли как-то прицепить сертификат при перенаправлении (именно метод `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url, false)`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Такая возможность в протоколе HTTP(S) не предусмотрена.

Comment: Очень жаль. Тащить сертификат через FE очень не хотелось бы.